# Using multiple modules in same project to maintain two versions of an app Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to manage a free and paid version of my app in Android Studio. Is it possible to just make another module inside of the project, copy all the code from the other module into that module, and then make the changes required for the paid version without having to make a new, separate project?

Comment: I would just turn the free app into a library project when you need to compile the paid app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to do that. Gradle supports a concept called [build variants](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants):

> The build system uses *product flavors* to create different product versions of your app. Each product version of your app can have different features or device requirements. The build system also uses build types to apply different build and packaging settings to each product version. Each product flavor and build type combination forms a build variant. The build system generates a different APK for each build variant of your app.

This allows you to have shared code/resources in your `src/main` folder and flavor specific code in a `src/free` or `src/paid` folders (assuming your product flavors are called 'free' and 'paid').

Although in most cases, you'll get better reach, combined ratings, less user confusion (two apps to choose from, how do I switch from free to paid, etc) and more opportunities to sell users on your app if you use [In-App Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) rather than create separate apps.

Comment: I need separate resource files as well as code. Can I accomplish that with build variants?

Comment: Yes, resources, dependencies, and code can all be unique to different variants.